# Uploading images from an HTML form to a custom Java HTTP Server producing unusual characters

Tags: java, html, http, post

```
I have programmed a custom build HTTP Server in Java.  My server runs an HTML form that allows the user to upload images.  The server received the POST message with the form data.  But when I try and parse the image data I'm getting replacement characters rather than Base64 data that represents the image.
```

1. How can I get my response to produce base64 image data?
2. For the response that I'm currently getting its my understanding that its replacement characters.  How does this compare to the normal character sets such as ANSI?

My HTML form I have this:

```
    <form name ="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload a File:
        <input type="file" name="the_file"  onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
        <img id='output' style="height:100px; width:100px;"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Upload">
    </form>
```

A partial code for my server is:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                            BufferedOutputStream dataOut = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                            String input = "";

                            while (true)
                            {
                                byte[] data = new byte[10000];
                                int size = bis.read(data);
                                if (size == -1) break;
                                
                                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                                {
                                    char c = (char)data[i];
                                    
                                    if (c != '\n')
                                    {                                            
                                        input += c;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            
                                        if (image_data == false)
                                        {
                                            System.out.println(input);
                                            
                                            if (input.contains("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"the_file\""))
                                            {
                                                image_data = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            
                                             if (input.contains("-----"))
                                            {
                                                 System.out.println("end of data");                  
                                                
                                                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 500; i2++)
                                                {
                                                    char c2 = string.charAt(i2);
                                                    System.out.print(c2);
                                                }
                                                System.out.println();
                                                                                                    
                                                image_data = false;
                                            }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 string += input;
                                             }
                                        }
```

The results I'm getting:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGGNS.png)

Answer (score 0):

(I would comment but my reputation does not allow that)

To my understanding, `multipart/form-data` does not send files encoded in base64 format, but rather in literal UTF-8 encoding.

For example, if you were to send a file containing `hello\n`, the content you would receive on your server would be `hello\n` (same as contents), instead of `aGVsbG8=` (base64-encoded).

As such, you should probably handle the request by writing it out to a file, as it is not readable in the terminal.